# How could I get access to socket.io.min.js in express?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I can connect socket.io through this url: localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js
But I need minified version! localhost/socket.io/socket.io.MIN.js is not works.

Comment: Are you sure you have the min file?

Comment: socket.io automatically serves a minified file when running in production mode. Why do you need/want a minified file during development?

Comment: This folder: "localhost/socket.io" does not exist! Is visible only for express, so I don't know, where exactly this file must be placed.

Comment: There's no minified version of socket.io client-slide API, you should minify it yourself.

Comment: More, are you run your socket.io in 80 port? If not, you should add your port also to get the script. For example if your socket.io runs in port 6000 it should be `http://localhost:6000/...`

Comment: Afshin Mehrabani, this version exists. It is located here: "node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\dist\socket.io.min.js"

Comment: I set 'production' envelopment mode, but still no changes. app.set('env', 'production');

Comment: Afshin Mehrabani, yes, I'm running socket.io and express on port 80.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Socket.IO intercepts requests to `/socket.io` to serve the files it needs. It normally serves them from:

`./node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist`

However, as said in [Socket.IO's wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/How-do-I-serve-the-client), you can serve the files yourself if you prefer.

The files you need are in the `/dist` folder in the [socket.io-client](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client) repo.

If you want to force production settings all the time, you can just add this to your node app right before calling `listen()`:

```
io.enable('browser client minification');  // send minified client
io.enable('browser client etag');          // apply etag caching logic based on version number
io.enable('browser client gzip');          // gzip the file
io.set('log level', 1);                    // reduce logging
io.set('transports', [                     // enable all transports (optional if you want flashsocket)
    'websocket'
  , 'flashsocket'
  , 'htmlfile'
  , 'xhr-polling'
  , 'jsonp-polling'
]);
```

Comment: This folder, the path to which you entered contains 4 files:socket.io.js
socket.io.min.js
WebSocketMain.swf
WebSocketMainInsecure.swf but only one is available - socket.io.js (in Express at this url: localhost/socket.io/).

Comment: You have 2 options. Either activate Socket.IO [production settings](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO) or you can serve the files yourself (just put them in a folder like `/public/javascripts/sio` and link directly to this folder in your client).

Comment: Still don't understand how to enable socket.io production mode, but thanks.

Comment: My english is bad, so I have a problems with documentation :(. I don't understand, where I must enter this: "NODE_ENV=production node app.js"

Comment: You are supposed to enter this in the terminal (or Windows Cmd) before you start your node app. In your case, I would advise to just change that in the code. I will update my answer.

Comment: "NODE_ENV" is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! the latest update of your answer - is that what I need!

Answer (score 1):

Latest **socket.io.js minified** version here, as of today (**version 0.9.16**):

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js